# Как правильно нарисовать график с датой в chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Пытаюсь сделать график с помощью chart.js

код:

```js
moment.locale('ru');
let ctx = $('#chart');
let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bars',
  data: [{
    x: new Date(2020, 7, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    y: 1
  }, {
    t: new Date(2020, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    y: 10
  }],
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='chart'></canvas>
```

Почему-то рисовать не хочет, вместо этого получается просто область с графиком, но не сам график.

Подскажите как быть?

Comment: не ваш случай - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911799/chart-js-date-and-time-bar-chart-not-rendering-line-works-though ?

Comment: спасибо добрый человек!